# Varnish with loadbalancer

Tags: varnish

Varnish has been applauded for various reasons. So, I am trying to setup varnish
in-front of loadbalancer, I am now able to setup varnish itself and which deals with 
all incoming traffic and sends required ones towards web-server with brilliant amount of caching, limiting traffic and nice set of vcl config which has ability to filter traffic based on IP, location, User agent and so on.

However, I am not convinced with the logic of pointing VARNISH IP as A record for the given 
domain's, (as I have around 15 domains).

Can someone kick my back and  please enlighten me how can varnish be configured so that I can still point loadbalancer IP as A record.

In other word how can i setup varnish to serve caching objects but not as DNS entry Point.

All in all I am looking varnish to serve static content and other cache-able objects
(which is really high in number along with some json object which in my test environment has performed brilliantly).

[note: I am not configuring varnish as loadbalancer]

Comment: Without more knowledge of your network topology and settings this can be difficult to answer. I'm also a little unclear as to your actual question. Is the question "How can I point some traffic to the Varnish cache and the rest directly to the load balancer"?

Comment: I would like to put varnish cache on the top of everything so that any request coming in should check for available objects if its there off you go if not only come to next layer which is webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your load balancer and Varnish cache IP addresses are both available to the clients, what you could do is branch off a new subdomain for each of the main domains that is specifically used for cached assets (such as `assets.domain.com`).

You would continue to point `domain.com` and `www.domain.com` to the load balancer (as it is currently configured). Then separately, create the `assets` subdomains and configure them to use the Varnish cache. You may want to configure Varnish to cache objects only in certain folders or of certain types.

After manually testing that `assets.domain.com` returns the objects you intend, you would then replace links to your assets using the `assets.domain.com` instead of `domain.com` or `www.domain.com` so end clients would start using the cache.

Comment: In other word how can i setup varnish to serve caching objects but not as DNS entry Point. -> meaning, customer comes to loadbalancer but i am looking for wayout to serve cached object first.

Comment: Without being a DNS entry point, it needs to be in line somewhere. If you already have 2 load balancers then you will likely want 2 Varnish cache in front of or behind the load balancer. However, those specific setups are going to require much more engineering to retain the same level of HA/fail over you already have.

Comment: hey andy thanks yes, varnish is infront of loadbalancer so i was wondering how can i send all traffic to Loadbalancer yet provide cache objects. Loadbalancer is hardware device and its hosted which is not an biggest issue.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood how Varnish worked... isn't that pretty much the default behavior? If the object doesn't match some expression then pass it to the backend web servers instead of serving it. Something like http://ultimatetutorial.com/2012/02/serving-static-files-using-varnish/

Answer (score -1):

One thought on solving this architecture question comes back to what you need infront of Varnish.

You will 99% of the time need a load balancing layer infront of Varnish as Varnish does not support SSL out of the box.
If you include the requirement for HA then you also need something infront of Varnish

The general way to solve the "Something infront" is an nginx layer. Guide on Varnish setup here:
https://www.section.io/varnish-install-quick-and-detailed/

Though this could also be an AWS ELB or any other load balancer.

For some more details instruction we'll need to understand your application requirements.